# Number of divergence free symmetric two tensor in dimension 4

Tags: co.combinatorics, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, general-relativity

In a  $4$ dimensional (semi)-Riemannian manifold $(M^{4}, g)$, both Einstein tensor $G= \operatorname{Ric}(g)- \frac{R(g)}{2}g$ and stress-energy tensor $T$ symmetric and divergence-free. Is there any counting formula for such types of tensors?

The divergence-freeness would imply that number of such tensors would be way less than $\frac{ n(n+1)}{2}.$ If the number is $1,$ Einstein's Field equations $G= \kappa T$ become trivial, and so it should not be the case. In fact, the Bach tensor (B) is another traceless symmetric and divergence-free tensor. Can you at least name a couple more of these types of tensors? Please don't tell me to take positive linear combinations of $G, T, B.$ I am looking for some counting formula like the formula that gives a total number of "independent" Riemann curvature tensor components. I am sorry if this question is too vague and naive. Thanks so much

Comment: I read in a French book by Barrau and Gray, that $G$ is the only tensor that may fit EFE (up to the presence of the cosmological constant) under linearity with respect to the Riemann tensor and another one IIRC but the authors don't provide the proof. I guess it is due to the need to recover Newton's theory at low energy.